# Load only audio from youtube in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube-api, audio-streaming

Is it possible to load **only the audio** from YouTube into my **AS3 flash custom player** through **youtube AS3 api**?

I want to load it into a sound object and then assign it to a sound channel.

I would like to know if there is an "**official**" way to do this, I'd like to avoid improvising (like loading the whole stream and then use only the audio).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read the YouTube terms of service carefully:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

In particular, you may not "promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API".

Doing so in any way (such as moving the video off stage) is likely to have your site blocked for playbacks by YouTube for breach of terms of service.

NB: YouTube manages to provide the service it does through advertising on top of video content. Separating the content like this prevents YouTube from making any money from the service it is providing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it for private usage, its okay I guess.

After some research work with different APIs and libraries and researching source code, I just tried it by myself and wolla.

Just saying, audio only links are in the page source of each video.

You just have to know what you are looking for ;)

Open a youtube video, view page source and search for "mime%3Daudio". There should be 5 matches, full url for example:

"https%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-35cxanpbo5a-8pxl.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsource%3Dyoutube%26signature%3D30EC556F55533FBFD9003767730D10556681F33A.B12E021CA54CCB9E225F58A4430E9BB528081FB5%26requiressl%3Dyes%26expire%3D1527306011%26clen%3D3064602%26initcwndbps%3D1152500%26ipbits%3D0%26mime%3Daudio%252Fmp4%26dur%3D192.911%26fvip%3D5%26lmt%3D1524946334873350%26key%3Dyt6%26sparams%3Dclen%252Cdur%252Cei%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%26itag%3D140%26gir%3Dyes%26ip%3D81.217.53.239%26id%3Do-ALNxMeQYw4LLc1FAjxt4h795wKTdqJnzc_SBgzEJVBxR%26c%3DWEB%26keepalive%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C29%26mn%3Dsn-35cxanpbo5a-8pxl%252Csn-2gb7sn7r%26ei%3Du4IIW7DfC46rgAfrrpnICw%26ms%3Dau%252Crdu%26mt%3D1527284230%26pl%3D16%26mv%3Dm"

Just decode URL and you got what you want.